# Drawables Ldpi Mdpi Hdpi Xhdpi

Tags: android, eclipse

Can Anyone tell the ratios of ldpi, mpdi, hdpi, and xhdpi? and also how can I tell if the phone/ tablet is in ldpi mdpi hdpi and xhdpi? Tnx in advance

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approximately 3:4:6:8 for the ldpi mdpi hdpi and xhdpi ratios.